# In a binary classification soft-margin SVM problem, is there a case where there are no bounded support vectors for one class?

Tags: svm

For two class labels +1 and -1, is there a case in conventional soft-margin SVM where one class does not have a margin support vector and just margin error support vectors or correct points?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. What do you mean by "margin error support vectors"?